# Drawing complete graph in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, graph

[image]

I want to draw a complete graph for these points with coordinates.
In an ArcMap environment, can a complete graph be drawn with points?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ArcPy:

```py
import arcpy, itertools

arcpy.env.overwriteoutput=True
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\GIS\ArcMap_default_folder\Default.gdb' #Change

points = r'graphpoints' #Your input points

pointlist = [p[0] for p in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points, 'SHAPE@XY')] #List all points
pointcombinations = [p for p in itertools.combinations(pointlist, 2)] #List all combinations of point pairs

#Create the lines (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/polyline.htm)
features = []
for feature in pointcombinations:
    features.append(arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in feature]), 
                                   arcpy.Describe(points).spatialreference))
    
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features, 'polylines') #Save. Change the name
```

[image]

Comment: Hello .My problem is solved .Thank you very much

Comment: Nice. Please accept (and upvote) my answer with the checkbox

Comment: Interesting! `itertools`, never used this, or even knew about it! :)  This is why I always like reading your answers you always seem to have some clever python approach.

Comment: :) thank you, it is very useful from problems like this!